# Leverage browser caching (PageSpeed Insights)

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, debian

I'm trying to pass Google Adsense warnings about what I should fix.
This caching stuff makes my butt hurt.
Running Debian 7 with Wordpress 3.7.1.
May be that Adsense just not love me?

Tried all I found on Google and sure on here.
Like:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 86400 seconds"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 86400 seconds"
</IfModule>
```

And similar:

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
 ExpiresActive on
 ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
 ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/x-ico "access plus 1 year"
 ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 14 days"
 ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 14 days"
 ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 14 days"
 ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 14 days"
 ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 14 days"
</IfModule>
```

And even this, which crashes WP:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|html|htm|xml|txt|xsl)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536050"
</FilesMatch>
```

Tried to add these lines in .htaccess at WP root and just in case in themes directory too.
Tried some WP plugins with no luck.

Comment: nice humor... first paragraph :)

Comment: Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking.

Will try later. ;)

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. Strange limitation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Found solution:**

> on debian based distro's it is as easy to do as typing then a2enmod
>   headers and a2enmod expire

Source: http://forum.slicehost.com/index.php?p=/discussion/3400/install-apache-modules/p1